# Using count inside pivot table Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count values from a column called "profitable_trades". This values are "TRUE" or "FALSE" depending if they are <0 or not. The problem I'm facing is that seems you can't use COUNT with Numpy. Is that correct?

What I want to know it's how many TRUE or FALSE I have for each item.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
currencies = ['audcad','audchf','audjpy','cadchf','eurcad','gbpaud','gbpchf','nzdusd']

filtered_df = df[df['Item'].isin(currencies)]

df3 = pd.pivot_table(filtered_df,index=["profitable_trades","month"],columns=["Item"],values=["profitable_trades"],aggfunc=[np.count],margins=True)
```

Here is the output:

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'count'

Any idea about how to use count inside a pivot table?

Thanks!

Comment: `np.count` is not a thing. You should be able to just use `'count'`

Comment: Hello Chris, I tried your solution and I get the following error: NameError: name 'count' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.count` does not exist. You can just use `aggfunc = len`:

```
df3 = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index=["profitable_trades","month"],
    columns=["Item"],
    aggfunc=len,
    margins=True
)
```

Comment: Hello mck, thanks for your answer, after trying it I see another problem/error: ValueError: Grouper for 'profitable_trades' not 1-dimensional. Any clue?

Comment: great! Now it's working! but @mck, I don't understand what before it was a mistake. Could you give me a brief explanation? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @darcy if you're just counting, you don't need to specify any `values` because they are irrelevant. Kindly accept the answer if it's helpful :)